# How to distribute weights in weighted average in order to obtain a known value

Tags: probability, weighted-mean

I'd like to know if there is a way to calculate the weights in a weighted average, in order to obtain a fixed, known value.

In other words, given the weighted average formula:

$$Z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n s_i w_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}$$

where $Z$ is the final weighted average, $s_1...s_n$ are the values, and $w_1...w_n$ are the weights and $Z$ and $s_1...s_n$ are known and positive.

Is there a way to calculate $w_1...w_n$?

Note that $w_i>0$ for all $i > 0$

Comment: It is possible if $n=2$ and $Z$ is in the interval $(s_{(1)},s_{(2)})$, but otherwise there will usually be too many unknowns and so many possible solutions

Comment: "Many possible solutions" is usually not a problem. Since $Z$ is a convex combination of the $s_i$ and all convex subsets of real numbers are intervals, every possible real value between the minimum of the $s_i$ and maximum of the $s_i$ (inclusive) can be obtained in this way.  In fact, if you limit the nonzero $w_i$ to one corresponding to the minimum and one corresponding to the maximum, it's easy to write a simple formula. This is purely a matter of arithmetic.  Could you explain what the intended statistical application might be?

Comment: Indeed. I hoped I missed something or ignored some different approach, but indeed there are too many unknowns and not enough assumptions. I have worked around the problem by not using a weighted mean, but an algorithm using brute force to obtain the closest value to $Z$ in a reasonable number of iterations. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Iteration is unnecessary: algebra produces the answer with a simple closed formula.

Comment: @whuber Yet I don't see your answer...

Comment: I'm sorry; I thought it was already apparent in the comment offered by @Henry and the answer posted by Apprentice.  Without any loss of generality, sort the values so that $s_1$ is the smallest value and $s_n$ is the largest.  Using only two weights (with all the others set to zero), $w_1+w_n=1$ implies $w_n=1-w_1.$ Therefore $Z=w_1s_1+(1-w_1)s_n$ has the *unique* solution $w_1=(Z-s_n)/(s_1-s_n)$ (provided $s_n\ne s_1$). Both weights are nonnegative if and only if $s_1 \le Z \le s_n.$

Comment: @whuber thanks for that, but as I told Apprentice and specified in the question (last line) one constraint I have is that all the weights must be strictly positive.

Comment: You can make all the other weights arbitrarily small.  One way to express this fact is to set $w_2=w_3=\cdots=w_{n-1}=\epsilon$ to be a positive number.  The equation now is $$Z=w_1 s_1 + \epsilon(s_2+s_3+\cdots+s_{n-1}) + w_n s_n = w_1 s_1 + \epsilon S + (1-w_1-(n-2)\epsilon)s_n$$ where $S=s_2+s_3+\cdots+s_{n-1}.$ The solution is $w_1 = (Z-\epsilon S + ((n-2)\epsilon-1)s_n)/(s_1-s_n)$ and all coefficients are positive when $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small. This can be assured provided $s_1\lt Z\lt s_n.$ That's why "$\gt0$" and "$\ge0$" aren't really different constraints.

Comment: Thank you whuber. "You can make all the other weights arbitrarily small.": I cannot do that. Basically I cannot manipulate $w_i$ in any way, since I need their value based _only_ on $Z$.

Comment: That makes no sense: you ask for a solution, which means you *do* contemplate varying the weights; and now you assert you cannot vary them.  What really is your question??

Comment: @whuber I took for granted that the weights must be inversely proportional to the respective values. You're right, that was far from being obvious, sorry.

Comment: It's neither obvious nor even mathematically possible for the weights to be inversely proportional to the values: what would happen when any of the $s_i$ are non-positive?

Comment: It is written in the question that "$Z$ and $s_1...s_n$ are known and positive".

Comment: Although that is true, the mathematical aspects of this problem do not change when a constant is added to all the $s_i$ and to $Z:$ a solution of one becomes a solution of the other.  Thus, the positivity is irrelevant.

Comment: All right, but it does changes for the context I am working with: what I have is a list of values ($s_1...s_n$), all of them positive. I need to pick up one of them randomly, but conditionally to their value: the greater the value, the smaller the chances to be picked up. The average value must be a known value $Z$. So I need to found the weights $w_1...w_n$ in order to respect this scenario. Since all of the values must have the chance to be picked up, any negative weight would make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Pick $w_1, w_2 \neq 0$ and $w_3 = \dots = w_n = 0$.

You get

$$
s_1w_1 + s_2w_2 = Z(w_1+w_2) \Rightarrow w_1 = \frac{(Z-s_2)w_2}{s_1-Z}.
$$

Pick any value of $w_2$, and you get the corresponding $w_1$.

For example $w_2 = 1$, and $w_1 = \frac{Z-s_2}{s_1-Z}$ satisfies the relation.

For $w_i >0$ for $i = 1,\dots, n$, let $w_i = w/n$ and $\bar{s} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n s_i$.

We have that

$$
\bar{s}w = Zw \Rightarrow w = \frac{1}{\bar{s}-Z}.
$$

The solution is positive as long as $\bar{s} > Z.$

Comment: thanks for that, but all the elements of the `w` set must be positive. My bad, I forgot to mention that, sorry. I have updated my question.

Comment: why don't you write down the assumptions on the $s_i$ and the $Z$? The solution I wrote have positive $w$ for $Z>s_2$ and $Z<s_1$.

Comment: The only assumption I can do on $s_i$ and $Z$ is that $s_0 < Z < s_i$, being $s_i$ of arbitrary cardinality.

Comment: I guess you mean $s_1 < Z < s_i$, for all $i>1$.

Comment: No, I mean $s_0<Z<s_i$, because $w_i$ contains only positive values (question updated).

Comment: In that case, my solution provides positive $w_1$ and $w_2$.

Comment: What is $s_0$??? you define $s$ with indices starting from $1$. Also what you mean by positive??? Strictly positive $w_i>0$? Please be more precise!

Comment: I'm so used to think in 0-based sets that I mixed up. Sorry, you're right, forget about $s_0$. $w_i > 0$, strictly positive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129806/discussion-between-luca-fagioli-and-apprentice).